Publish To IIS on Azure Windows VM from MacOS
Currently, I have a .NET application that I can publish locally on a Mac machine and FTP to IIS hosted on an Azure VM.
Is there an automated way to do the publish?
I've come across instructions for WebDeploy however it seems like WebDeploy won't work when publishing from a Mac.
Edit:
So I would like to:

publish the .NET application
deploy it to the IIS hosted on Azure VM from Mac OS without manually transferring the published files


"I can publish locally and FTP to IIS", but you cannot automate that? Some shell scripts can carry out the same. You will have to edit the question to show what exactly you wanted. WebDeploy is not working from Mac, for which you got it right.

@LexLi, original question has been edited.
Looks like there is some nice automation available to accomplish this on a Windows machine, but not Mac.
I guess I can write a shell script.  But in general, FTP is not recommended from shell script.  I believe IIS does not support SFTP or SSH.
Regardless, I was hoping there would be a similar way to deploy from my Mac dev machine to IIS similar to what is available on Windows.

@LexLi,  just to clarify.  If the source machine is running MacOS and the target machine is Windows, with Web Deploy installed on Windows, it will not work?
MacOS -> Windows (WebDeploy)

WebDeploy requires both client/server side, so please forget about it as you won't have the client side bits running on Mac. "But in general, FTP is not recommended from shell script" is not true, as FTP over SSL (FTPS) is still a feasible option out there. "I believe IIS does not support SFTP or SSH" is not true either, as recent Windows releases have OpenSSH built-in, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_overview

Thanks @LexLi.  I figured there was a client side aspect of WebDeploy that wouldn't work.  Thanks for confirming

Unlike the features available in Visual Studio on Windows, there doesn't seem to be a convenient way to publish a ASP.NET app directly from the IDE.
For MacOS, Visual Studio is being retired this year.
I have found that there are no plugins available for Visual Studio on MacOS that will publish an app to IIS running on a Windows VM. This seems to be a limitation in that such plugins on Windows would use WebDeploy to deploy the app.  WebDeploy is not available on MacOS.
So right now, the steps to publish the app from MacOS are:

Publish you app via dotnet publish
FTP your publish folder to your Windows VM under the IIS wwwroot folder

